# How to create expiry date attribute without time in Magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have created an expiry_date attribute in Magento admin.I have display expiry_date in sales order in admin.It is successfully displayed.But I have a problem with time.My requirement is the only date will display without time.Please check my screenshot.https://prnt.sc/hgngyb.Can you please help me?

Comment: you need to overide that file and do it manually.

Comment: add your code of adding expiry date in sales order.